# Select distinct and inner join a image data type

Tags: sql, distinct, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to select all the unique customers who have placed an Order, but when I try to include the Photo I get an error.

```
Order Table
ID      |  CustomerID
-----------------------
1       |  2
2       |  1
3       |  2


Customer Table
ID      | Name   | Photo (image, null)
--------------------------
1       | John   | image
2       | Adam   | image
3       | Jack   | image


Expected result
   CustomerID  | Name   | Photo
--------------------------------
1              | John   | image
2              | Adam   | image
```

And my query so far:

```
SELECT Distinct o.CustomerID, c.Name, c.Photo
FROM Order o 
inner join Customer c on o.CustomerID = o.ID
```

This gives the following error:

> **The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not
>   comparable.**

Comment: where is the `DISTINCT` in the query?

Comment: Sorry, added it to the sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should be

```
select * from customers where id in (select customerID from orders)
```